# How to put constants in code memory

Tags: c++, c, linux, llvm, x86-64

I need to keep some information about each function in my program in the form of a constant number. I was wondering if it is possible to put the constant for a function just before it in the code memory, so if a function is called through a function pointer, that information could be read by subtracting the value of the function pointer.

To illustrate further, my code memory should look as follows.

```
ConstantForFunc1
Func1:
 ....

ConstantForFunc2
Func2:
 ....
```

And following is an example code of how I would read that information

```
FuncPointer f = &Func2;
int constantForFunc2 = *((int*)(f - sizeof(int)));
```

And note that using Hash tables is too slow for what I'm trying to achieve, so I need a very fast method. And all this modification, which is inserting constants and code to read from them is done by a compiler pass, which I'm writing and which modifies the LLVM IR. Using structures would be too cumbersome for the compiler pass, as it would have to modify a lot of code.

Comment: What. No. You need to describe a problem instead of describing a solution.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a portable way. Also, why `- 4`? And do you have in mind, that pointers can have different sizes?

Comment: Why not simple define a proper constant variable? E.g. `const int constantForFunc2 = 2;`

Comment: The only case where code like this would make any sense whatsoever is perhaps when writing embedded bootloaders or non-volatile memory programming algorithms. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Compilers will optimize the layout so putting a constant before a function in a code file doesn't guarantee it will be there in the compiled binary.

Comment: Typical "XY" question, you have a problem, X, which you think should be solved by doing Y, so you ask how to do Y. Describe what you are actually trying to achieve, and we can probably help.

Comment: I'm not writing a bootloader, but a compiler pass, that achieves some purpose. Like Tolga said, structures could be used, but that would require a lot of change to the code by the compiler pass, while the solution I'm describing seems easier to do if possible. I could also use hash tables, but hashing is too slow for this purpose.

Comment: Unless you use compiler-specific features or assembly, you can't embed data into code like that as it's not something standard C++ has support for.

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to insert anything into the assembly code you generate with your "compiler pass", you just insert that thing. Or are you doing something else?

Comment: @Alexey Frunze, My compiler pass works with LLVM intermediate representation code (IR).

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with LLVM IR, so I don't know if you can easily force it do something like this.

Comment: This makes _no_ sense in C/C++ (as languages), and you are fooling around with an LLVM pass anyway. I think this question is (a) an XY-question, (b) not at the right place in C/C++.

Comment: Does it have something to do with GHC's Tables-Next-To-Code (TNTC) optimization?

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing doesn't make sense, yet:

You could use structs maybe?

```
struct example
{
  int constantForFunc;
  void (*ptrToFunc)();
};

//After declaring, maybe 3, functions

struct example funcList[3] = {{5, &func1}, {10, &func2}, {15, &func3}};

int currentFuncConstant=funcList[1].constantForFunc;
(*funcList[1].ptrToFunc)();
```

I haven't used function pointers to be honest, probaby has mistakes.

Comment: I was thinking something like that too.

Comment: Ya but that requires a lot of change to the code, and I'm writing a compiler pass. It would be difficult to write a compiler pass that modifies the code so much.

Comment: And a searchable data structure either containing constants or pointing to them. The function pointer would be the key/index into the structure.

Comment: Alexey, Yes hash could be used, but hashing is slow for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: For my purpose, hashing is slow.

Comment: In your case the key is already a number. So you may use something extremely simple like `func % 1000` or even `func << N >> N` as a hash function. It gets some last digits of your func address. If fucntions are closely located, then collisions are not very probable.

Comment: NIA-You are right, but in my case, there should be no collisions at all.

Comment: @user1018562 You should probably put @ before usernames when replying to specific users so they can see your comments as notifications.

Comment: @user1018562, I didn't mean that my functions are ideal, I meant that you can try to invent the best-fitting hash function based on your context. But... no collisions... OK, I give up. Your requirements seem too idealistic for a simple solution. I think at first you could try any of suggested solutions and then see if it is actually slow or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not acceptable at all?:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int Const__Fxn1 = 1;
void Fxn1()
{
  cout << "Fxn1" << endl;
}

const int Const__Fxn2 = 2;
void Fxn2()
{
  cout << "Fxn2" << endl;
}

#define GetFxnConst(FxnName) Const__ ## FxnName

int main()
{
  cout << GetFxnConst(Fxn1) << endl;
  cout << GetFxnConst(Fxn2) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Option 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const volatile int v1 = 0;
volatile unsigned v2 = 0;

void Fxn1()
{
  if (v1) { v2 = 0x12345601; }
  cout << "Fxn1" << endl;
}

void Fxn2()
{
  if (v1) { v2 = 0x12345602; }
  cout << "Fxn2" << endl;
}

int FindFxnConst(void(*f)())
{
  const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)f;
  while (memcmp(p, "\x56\x34\x12", 3))
    p++;
  return p[-1];
}

int main()
{
  Fxn1();
  cout << FindFxnConst(Fxn1) << endl;
  Fxn2();
  cout << FindFxnConst(Fxn2) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/AGwYJX)):

```
Fxn1
1
Fxn2
2
```

You can embed more than 8 bits of data per function by using other magic prefixes, e.g.:

```
  if (v1)
  {
    v2 = 0x12345611; // byte 1
    v2 = 0x789ABC22; // byte 2
    v2 = 0xDEF01233; // byte 3
    v2 = 0xFEDCBA44; // byte 4
  }
```

This is not necessarily a reliable solution, let alone portable.

Comment: Actually my solution should work for function pointers. With function pointers, you don't have the name of the function, just its address.

Comment: Got it. But if you keep names for long enough, this could work. The thing is, at one point you get function addresses from function names anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since the addresses of the functions are known from the executable binary (unless they are loaded from a shared library ofcourse), if you have the address space layout randomization (ASLR) off, you could use [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) to generate a highly efficient hash function for you and use that hash function to get the constants for each function.

However, for this, you will have to compile your program twice, first to get the addresses of the functions from the generated binary, so that you could give those addresses as an input to `gperf` and recompile using the hash function generated by `gperf`. But you have to be careful that the addresses of the functions from the first compilation do not become different in the second compilation. I am not sure, how to achieve that.

An alternative, would be to do something like `gperf` just after your program is loaded, so you don't have to compile twice. But I don't know how to do that.